# Запуск UWP приложения из другой программы

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, windows-10

Есть UWP приложение, его нужно запустить из другой программы, запуск `.exe` не удаётся. Как можно корректно реализовать вызов UWP приложения из другого приложения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно [этому](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12927313/2003555) ответу нужно иметь идентификатор вызываемого приложения, далее `appUserModelId`. Ну и запустить приложение с помощью `ApplicationActivationManager` который надо предварительно импортировать из COM

```
    public enum ActivateOptions
    {
        None = 0x00000000,  // No flags set
        DesignMode = 0x00000001,  // The application is being activated for design mode, and thus will not be able to
        // to create an immersive window. Window creation must be done by design tools which
        // load the necessary components by communicating with a designer-specified service on
        // the site chain established on the activation manager.  The splash screen normally
        // shown when an application is activated will also not appear.  Most activations
        // will not use this flag.
        NoErrorUI = 0x00000002,  // Do not show an error dialog if the app fails to activate.                                
        NoSplashScreen = 0x00000004,  // Do not show the splash screen when activating the app.
    }


    //Импортируем интерфейс
    [ComImport, Guid("2e941141-7f97-4756-ba1d-9decde894a3d"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    interface IApplicationActivationManager
    {
        // Activates the specified immersive application for the "Launch" contract, passing the provided arguments
        // string into the application.  Callers can obtain the process Id of the application instance fulfilling this contract.
        IntPtr ActivateApplication([In] String appUserModelId, [In] String arguments, [In] ActivateOptions options, [Out] out UInt32 processId);
        IntPtr ActivateForFile([In] String appUserModelId, [In] IntPtr /*IShellItemArray* */ itemArray, [In] String verb, [Out] out UInt32 processId);
        IntPtr ActivateForProtocol([In] String appUserModelId, [In] IntPtr /* IShellItemArray* */itemArray, [Out] out UInt32 processId);
    }

    //Импортируем реализацию интерфейса
    [ComImport, Guid("45BA127D-10A8-46EA-8AB7-56EA9078943C")]//Application Activation Manager
    class ApplicationActivationManager : IApplicationActivationManager
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)/*, PreserveSig*/]
        public extern IntPtr ActivateApplication([In] String appUserModelId, [In] String arguments, [In] ActivateOptions options, [Out] out UInt32 processId);
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        public extern IntPtr ActivateForFile([In] String appUserModelId, [In] IntPtr /*IShellItemArray* */ itemArray, [In] String verb, [Out] out UInt32 processId);
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        public extern IntPtr ActivateForProtocol([In] String appUserModelId, [In] IntPtr /* IShellItemArray* */itemArray, [Out] out UInt32 processId);
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ApplicationActivationManager appActiveManager = new ApplicationActivationManager();//Class not registered
            uint pid;
            appActiveManager.ActivateApplication("2c123c17-8b21-4eb8-8b7f-fdc35c8b7718_n2533ggrncqjt!App", null, ActivateOptions.None, out pid);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Остается только найти этот самый `appUserModelId`, согласно тому же ответу из английского SO его можно найти в ветке HKCU 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И еще немнго про протокол активации:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/automate-launching-uwp-apps

Answer (score 0):

Можно решить проблему при помощи следующего кода на C++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <ShObjIdl.h>
#include <atlbase.h>

HRESULT LaunchApp(LPCWSTR AUMID)

{

HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    wprintf(L"LaunchApp %s: Failed to init COM. hr = 0x%08lx \n", AUMID, hr);
}
{
    CComPtr<IApplicationActivationManager> AppActivationMgr = nullptr;
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ApplicationActivationManager, nullptr,
            CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&AppActivationMgr));
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            wprintf(L"LaunchApp %s: Failed to create Application Activation Manager.hr = 0x%08lx \n", AUMID, hr);
        }
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        DWORD pid = 0;
        hr = AppActivationMgr->ActivateApplication(AUMID, nullptr, AO_NONE,
            &pid);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            wprintf(L"LaunchApp %s: Failed to Activate App. hr = 0x%08lx \n", AUMID, hr);
        }
    }
}
CoUninitialize();
return hr;

}


int main()

{
    LPCWSTR id = L"0245c1a2-da90-47fc-baec-c0d81db40d77_nkmqfabk7hsn6!App";
    LaunchApp(id);
    return 0;

}
```

где `LPCWSTR id` - это  `AUMID` — имя семейства пакетов с идущими за ним восклицательным знаком и идентификатором приложения.Имя семейства пакетов можно найти в файле  `Package.appxmanifest` вашего `UWP` приложения.Идентификатор приложения можно найти  в том же `Package.appxmanifest` (открытом в представлении `XML`) в разделе `<Applications>`